# Question about the composite body algorithm implementation in Drake

Tags: drake

I am trying to relate algorithm 9.3 in Jain to the implementation of the composite body algorithm in Drake.

The documentation mentions that the hinge matrix is the transpose of that used in Jain. Looking in Featherstone (2008), it seemed this implementation was more in the spirit of section 6.3 of featherstone, i.e. S*=H, and the matrix is calculated as columns rather than blockwise. I wanted to double check if this was the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. Although we use Jain's formulation and terminology (mostly) we like to think of the joint motion matrix as a small Jacobian as Featherstone does with his "S" (∂V/∂v, i.e. partial of spatial velocity V across the joint w.r.t. generalized velocities v of that joint). That way our H matrix follows the same orientation convention as does our full robotics Jacobian (where J maps velocites and Jᵀ maps forces).

We don't necessarily write down the H matrix for a given joint but rather have that joint (technically, mobilizer) provide functions for multiplying by H and Hᵀ.

Comment: Thank you! :) When the H matrix is calculated using CalcAcrossNodeJacobianWrtVExpressedInWorld, what is the relationship (if any) to section 3.6 of Jain? I believe H^* theta_dot is calculated using CalcAcrossMobilizerSpatialVelocity, however, I wasn’t sure why the generalised velocities were set to 1.0 using v(imob) = 1.0? It also wasn’t clear how this part of the computation relates to the pick-off operator B* if this is what is happening here?

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that we think of Jain's Spatial Operators as conceptual rather than computational. We don't form those huge matrices and then extract things as is being done in 3.6 (as I read it).

Comment: To understand CalcAcrossNodeJacobianWrtVExpressedInWorld() there are a few steps:
- Mobilizers (tree joints) connect two frames: "F" on the inboard body and "M" on the outboard body. Drake's documentation has a nice picture: https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_joint.html
- Thus the hinge matrix known to the joint relates those two frames: H_FM and we have V_FM = H_FM * v where V_FM is the spatial velocity (a 6-vector) of frame M in frame F., expressed in F.

Comment: That is, V_FM = joint.CalcAcrossMobilizerSpatialVelocity(v) so that function just calculates H_FM * v. CalcAcrossNodeJacobianWrtVExpressedInWorld() is required to return H_PB_W, that is the matrix that gives V_PB_W = H_PB_W * v. P is the inboard (parent) body frame onto which F is fixed, B is the outboard body frame onto which M is fixed. For that the function must use the available joint-specific function to calculate H_FM, then shift that to produce H_PB, then reexpress that in the World frame W.

Comment: Given only a function that computes H_FM * v, how can you obtain H explicitly? Easy -- just set elements of v to 1 to pick off columns of H_FM one at a time. That's what is going on there. Once the code computes H_FM it can create H_PB_W.